# Extract properties from a string value in GTM

Tags: javascript, string, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to pull out information from an old AWIN tag we have on the site with GTM. We're working on getting this pushed into the DataLayer, but that will take a while, so this is the next step for the time being.

Ive managed to pull the information into a string in GTM which is returning a value of the below (ive manually removed the values for this post), which is great:

> '/*** Do not change** / var AWIN = {}; AWIN.Tracking = {};
>   AWIN.Tracking.Sale =  {}; / **Set your transaction parameters ***/
>   AWIN.Tracking.Sale.amount = "00.00"; AWIN.Tracking.Sale.channel =
>   "aw"; AWIN.Tracking.Sale.currency = "GBP"; AWIN
>   .Tracking.Sale.orderRef = "00000"; AWIN.Tracking.Sale.parts =
>   "DEFAULT:00.00" ; AWIN.Tracking.Sale.test = "0";
>   AWIN.Tracking.Sale.voucher = "";'

The only part i need is the value of

> AWIN.Tracking.Sale.parts.

The script we've created to extract this is:

```
function() {
  var awintrackstr = {{DOM - AWIN Image Full}};
  return awintrackstr.match(/AWIN.Tracking.Sale.parts = \"(.*)\";$/)[1];
}
```

However, this is extracting everything past that the value we need:

> 'DEFAULT:00:00"; AWIN.Tracking.Sale.test = "0"; AWIN.Tracking.Sal....

All the tests we've created shows the above should work, but its not working in GTM

Has anyone got any ideas of how this should work in GTM? Again, all we're looking to exctract is the part that says **DEFAULT:00.00**.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the `"(.*)"` part in your regular expression.
`.*` will match anything, including other `"` characters, making it match up to the last `"` that is still followed by the rest of your regular expression.

Replace `"(.*)"` with `"([^"]*)"`, this will match any character that is **not** `"`.

I can also recommend using [regex101.com](http://regex101.com) whenever you need to write a regular expression. Using this, you will also notice the `"` character has no special meaning in a javascript regular expression, so there is no need to escape it.

Edit: here is the modified version of your regular expression at work: https://regex101.com/r/TPUU6z/1

Comment: Hi Delvian, that's brilliant - thank you very much for answering. I was able to get it working with your help. I had to change my code slightly in a different way by removing the $ to read '

`function() {
  var awintrackstr = {{DOM - AWIN Image Full}};
  return awintrackstr.match(/AWIN.Tracking.Sale.parts = \"([^"]*)\";/)[1];
}`

but it was your answer that got this working.

Thank you